# List index out of range and random number to choose an item in list

Tags: python, list, random, split

I need to make a list of iPhone models from a string using `.split()`.

That's not a problem, but I also have to use a random number from 0-9 to pick a word,
then display 3 random words using while/for loop.

In my code, when I enter:

```
import random

iPhone = 'Original 3G 3GS 4 4S 5 5C 5S 6 6Plus'.split()

z = 0
while z < 4:
    for y in range (1,3):
        for x in iPhone:
            x = random.randint(0,10)
            print (iPhone[x])
```

It says:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\zteusa\Documents\AZ_wordList2.py", line 15, in <module>
        print (iPhone[x])
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure whats causing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both arguments to `random.randint` are inclusive:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(0, 1)
1
>>> random.randint(0, 1)
0
>>>
```

So, when you do `x = random.randint(0,10)`, `x` could sometimes be equal to `10`.  But your list `iPhone` only has ten items, which means that the maximum index is `9`:

```
>>> iPhone = 'Original 3G 3GS 4 4S 5 5C 5S 6 6Plus'.split()
>>> len(iPhone)
10
>>> iPhone[0]  # Python indexes start at 0
'Original'
>>> iPhone[9]  # So the max index is 9, not 10
'6Plus'
>>> iPhone[10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

You need to do:

```
x = random.randint(0, 9)
```

so that `x` will always be within the range of valid indexes for `iPhone`.

---

Regarding your comments, you said that you need to print three random items from the list.  So, you could do something like this:

```
import random

iPhone = 'Original 3G 3GS 4 4S 5 5C 5S 6 6Plus'.split()

z = 0
while z < 3:
    x = random.randint(0,9)
    print (iPhone[x])
    z += 1  # Remember to increment z so the while loop exits when it should
```

Comment: Where should I put the `print (iPhone[x])` so it will print a random item in the list 3 times? @iCodez

Comment: I keep forgetting that [0] is the first :(

Comment: I have edited my answer to do what I think you want.  If it is still incorrect, then you need to include some sample output in your question.

Comment: It does not. I need the out put to be 3 of the 10 items in the list, for example original \n 4 \n 5